# PHP returns element with name instead of ID

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, getelementbyid

In the following PHP code `DOMDocument::getElementById` returns the node `<a name="test">`instead of the node `<div id="test">`:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<a name="test"></a><div id="test"></div>'); // triggers duplicate ID warning
echo $doc->getElementById("test")->nodeName; // outputs "a"
?>
```

This happens only for `<a>`nodes. Is this intended?

JavaScript handles it as I expected:

```js
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<a name="test"></a><div id="test"></div>';
    console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
});
</script>
```

EDIT (question was marked as duplicate): This question is not about wether I should use `name` or `id` and also not about using both `name` and `id`, but why PHP finds nodes with `name` attribute when I search for an id.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614586/dom-error-id-someanchor-already-defined-in-entity-line-x

Comment: Have you tried: `$doc->getAttribute('id')` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Comment: Kenneth Bregat This would just get me the id of the document. I try to get the node with an specific id. Unfortunately I can not change the HTML, but have to parse it and there is another `<a>` node with the name attribute. It is not hard to work around, but I was wondering why it is not working as I expected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of HTML5, the `name` attribute [isn't supported](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp) in `a` tags so it looks like it's changed to an `id` attribute.

Comment: The page I am trying parse is XHTML 1.0, but I guess you are right and PHP does not really care about the Doctype.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a hold-over from PHP emulating old IE behaviour. In IE 7 and earlier, document.getElementById() did indeed treat name attributes on `<a>` elements as if they were id attributes and so would match the `<a>` element rather than the `<div>` element. IE has long since moved on, but PHP it seems, on this point, has not.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#an-indicated-part-of-the-document)

> For HTML documents (and the text/html MIME type), the following processing model must be followed to determine what the indicated part of the document is.
>
> Parse the URL, and let fragid be the  component of the URL.
> If fragid is the empty string, then the indicated part of the document is the top of the document.
> If there is an element in the DOM that has an ID exactly equal to fragid, then the first such element in tree order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.
> If there is an a element in the DOM that has a name attribute whose value is exactly equal to fragid, then the first such element in tree order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.
> Otherwise, there is no indicated part of the document.

When I pasted your code to PHP sandbox I noticed an interesting warning:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have this warning and somehow PHP interprets `<a name` as ID. Maybe @joelrosenthal is correct with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48931255/2731944).